# Passing a polymorphic SQLAlchemy object to another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I want to pass an SQLAlchemy object from one thread to another. The object is persistent in the database, but I don't need to modify it in the other thread. Reading the documentation it looks like I need to use `make_transient` before it's passed. This is working, except for an unusual quirk - the object I'm passing is polymorphic. It seems that the polymorphic attributes of the object appear as `None` in the other thread, unless they are accessed before they are passed. So I have a workaround, but I guess I'm doing something wrong.

```
myobject = session.query(MyObject).first()
myobject.someattribute  # without this, assert fails
make_transient(myobject)

# magic to pass to another thread
assert(myobject.someattribute is not None)
```

I'm working with PySide so the thread is done using `QtCore.QThread` but I don't think this should matter.

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you show us how your models are configured?